# Prevent jquery from multiple click function

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there a chance to adjust my code so when someone clicks button code would be executed only once? Not as many times as user clicks that button. Thanks
**HTML**

```
<button class="click_me">Click</button>
<div class="example">Some text</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.example{
    width:100px;
    padding:5px 5px;
    background:skyblue;
    color:white;
    display:none;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".click_me").click(function(){
    $(".example").slideDown();
    $(".example").delay("2000").slideUp();
});
```

Also check out my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/es11k54s/)!

```js
$(".click_me").click(function() {
  $(".example").slideDown();
  $(".example").delay("2000").slideUp();
});
```

```css
.example {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  background: skyblue;
  color: white;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="click_me">Click</button>
<div class="example">Some text</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`.one()` method](https://api.jquery.com/one/). In doing so, the function is only executed once.

From the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/one/):

> The `.one()` method will attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/eyyrd8yh/)

```
$(".click_me").one('click', function(){
    $(".example").slideDown();
    $(".example").delay("2000").slideUp();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = 0;

$(".click_me").click(function(){
    if ( ++x === 1 ) {
        $(".example").slideDown();
        $(".example").delay("2000").slideUp();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the button after click as well. I prefer this way because users will know that the button can not be clicked any more.

```
$(".click_me").click(function(){
    $(this).prop("disabled",true);
    $(".example").slideDown();
    $(".example").delay("2000").slideUp();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

as the user wrote before you can use the one function. but then the function really only got executed once.. and its not possible to execute it again.

adding and removing a class will do the trick.

```
$(".click_me").click(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('locked')) {
        $(".example").slideDown();
        $(".example").delay("2000").slideUp();
        $(this).addClass('locked');
    }
});
```

in this case you can for instance unlock the click by removing the class from the element. in your case after 2s... like:

```
$(".click_me").click(function(){
    $(this) = $this;
    if(!$this.hasClass('locked')) {
        $(".example").slideDown();
        $(".example").delay("2000").slideUp();
        $this.addClass('locked');
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
        $this.removeClass('locked')
    }, 2000);
});
```

greetings timmi